# What the difference between install & installing in that case?

Tags: verbs, differences

I have the following sentences:

> Turn off the internet connection before **install** the program.
>   Turn off the internet connection before **installing** the program.

`Install` and `installing` are verbs so, Why installing is correct & install is not?

Comment: I’m not sure what type of answer you’re looking for. Do you understand how prepositions work? (If not then you’re probably looking for ELL, not this site.) Are you looking for some etymological explanation?

Comment: @Laurel: The big trouble for me is prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

"Before install" is not grammatical.

"Before" can be either a preposition or a subordinating conjunction.

As a preposition, it takes a Noun Phrase, including (as one possibility) a clause headed by a gerund, such as "installing the program".

As a subordinating conjunction, it can take a finite clause, which includes a finite verb; but this normally needs to have the subject expressed. So "before you install the program" is fine. But "before install the program" is ungrammatical.

The only difference in meaning between "before installing the program" and "before you install the program" is that you have to specify a subject in the second case, so it can make it a bit more specific.